# Tomcat 404 – Not Found: when Implementing REST API

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, web.xml, http-response-codes

I'm trying to implement simple RESTFUL API service using dynamic web application in Eclipse. Every time I am getting error message `HTTP Status 404 – Not Found`.

I have attached my screen below

**Package structure**

[image: My RestFul API Code Picture]

I am able to run tomcat server on `localhost:8080` as shown on the above figure but when I trying to access my api path I am getting `404 not found error`

Here is my whole code

```
package com.restful.java.example;

import javax.ws.rs.*;

@Path("/")
public class ScoreService {
    private static int wins ,losses, ties;

    @GET
    @Path("/score")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String getScore() {
       String pattern = 
          "{ \"wins\":\"%s\", \"losses\":\"%s\", \"ties\": \"%s\"}";
       return String.format(pattern,  wins, losses, ties );   
    }
     //localhost:8080/restful-java/score?wins=2%losses=3@ties=15
    @PUT
    @Path("/score")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String updateScore( @QueryParam("wins")int wins,
                                @QueryParam("losses")int losses,
                                @QueryParam("ties")int ties) {
        ScoreService.wins = wins;
        ScoreService.losses = losses;
        ScoreService.ties = ties;
        String pattern = 
                  "{ \"wins\":\"%s\", \"losses\":\"%s\", \"ties\": \"%s\"}";
              return String.format(pattern,  wins, losses, ties );   


    }

    @POST @Path("/score/wins") @Produces("text/plain")
    public int increaseWins() {
        return ++wins;
    }
    @POST @Path("/score/ties") @Produces("text/plain")
    public int increaseTies() {
        return ++ties;
    }
    @POST @Path("/score/losses") @Produces("text/plain")
    public int increaseLosses() {
        return ++losses;
    }

    @GET @Path("/score/wins") @Produces("text/plain")
    public int getWins() {
        return wins;
    }

    @GET @Path("/score/losses") @Produces("text/plain")
    public int getLosses() {
        return losses;
    }

    @GET @Path("/score/ties") @Produces("text/plain")
    public int getTies() {
        return ties;
    }
}
```

Inside `Webcontent` I have `web.xml` and I have following code here:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>restful-java</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: @NicholasK. Will you please check my Post. you can see my screen and code . I have updated my post. I have not used any framework , In normal way I am trying REST API

Comment: What does your `web.xml` inside the `WEB-INF` look like?

Comment: @cokeby190. Please check my post . I have added my xml code which was inside WEB-INF

Comment: @NicholasK. I tried your way also it not working

Comment: Hi @NarayanGhimire, possible to try `http://localhost:8080/restful-java/resources/scores`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed the mapping in your `web.xml`. Add the following lines :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>My Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.restful.java.example</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>My Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Basically what this configuration is doing is mapping urls with pattern `/api/*` to a servlet which is required.

Also looks like you are using jersey for your REST implementation. Now you can try to access your api's using the following url:

`http://localhost:8080/restful-java/api/score`

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your Tomcat Web Server is property configured to deal with .java MIME type.

MIME types are used by Web Servers to determine how to serve up specific types of content. .jpg or .png for images, htm or html for web pages, or maybe .aspx or .java for executable scripts. The Web Server needs to know what command processor to use for each file type, and that's what the MIME types are used for. I'm betting you have no MIME type set up for .java files, which would be an entry in your config files for your web server. Research "Set Up Java MIME type on Tomcat".

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: Class level**

As you code suggests if you want to access:

```
http://localhost:8080/restful-java/score?wins=2%losses=3@ties=15
```

Then you are missing `/restful-java` text in the annotation for your `ScoreService` class.

*Replace:*

```
@Path("/")
```

*with:*

```
@Path("/restful-java")
```

**Option 2: Fix the PATH  and the URL you are using**

Remove `@Path("/")` annotation from your original code.

and try to access :

```
http://localhost:8080/score?wins=2%losses=3@ties=15
```

**Option 3: App configuration level**

Set `restful-java` as a mapping in the `web.xml` file (or remove it as indicated by @nicholas-k answer).

Note: you must remove `@Path("/")` annotation from your original code in order to make it works correctly.

Comment: what is the difference between [@Path("/")] and [@Path("/restful-java")]. After replacing also error is not solved

Comment: if you want to access `http://localhost:8080/restful-java/score?wins=2%losses=3@ties=15`  then restful-java has been defined as part of the PATH URL in your class, or as the context-name for your app

Comment: I have defined PATH URL in my class. But when I am trying to access it from browser I am getting `404 not found error.` I can run `localhost:8080` . But when I am running `http://localhost:8080/restful-java/score` I am getting 404 not found error

Comment: @NarayanGhimire Answer updated with 3 possible approaches for solving  `HTTP 404`

Comment: After updating xml file and accoring to suggestion of  `Nicholas K` ,I am finally succed. Thanks your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the latest versions of **both** Eclipse and Tomcat are installed, which (in 2021) are:

- Eclipse 2021
- Tomcat 10

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).